# Is there a convention on how to document a JavaScript file with comments? Like function signatures, examples, etc

Tags: javascript, comments, document

Java has Javadoc, Python has docstring. Is there something similar in JavaScript?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The most commonly used is JsDoc (https://jsdoc.app/).

This is also a tool that generates documentation from your sources, commented with JsDoc style: https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc